# How to initialize error type in if-else

Tags: go

In the code snippet below, how do I initialize an error variable?

```
err := nil                // can not compile, show "use of untyped nil"
if xxx {
    err = funcA()
} else {
    err = funcB()
}
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

As you can see above, `err` will be used in the if-else blocks. I want to use one variable to get the result, but how do I initialize `err` here. Thanks!

Comment: this should be shown in search engines as *golang declare nil error*

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can create a zero-valued error (which will be nil) by declaring the variable.

```
var err error
if xxx {
    err = funcA()
} else {
    err = funcB()
}
```

It's a common idiom, and you'll see it in plenty of code.

Answer (score 7):

This one looks a little hacky, but is valid too:

```
err := *new(error)
```

Comment: this is the valid way when you are doing the for loop eg. ```for val, err := value, *new(error); err != nil && val > 0; val, err = doStuff() {} ```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is simply:

```
err := error(nil)
```