# How to add conditional sentences in template

Tags: templates, go

How to write a conditional in Go Lang like this:

**File: view.html**

```
{{ if(var1 =="" && var2 =="" }}
ALL EMPTY
{{else}}
DISPLAY 
{{END}}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193208/how-to-initialize-error-type-in-if-else) and from the [golang](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if) website to get started

Answer (score 9):

Templates don't have operators, but they have function `eq`, which takes two arguments and returns true if they are equal, and function `and` which also takes two arguments and returns true if they're both true. So you could write the first line in your code as:

```
{{if (and (eq var1 "") (eq var2 ""))}}
```